# How to tell the difference between BOOL values in a dict: NO, nil, or doesn't exist

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I'm using a conditional statement such as

```
// isComplete is a BOOL value
if (![videoDictionary valueForKey:@"isComplete"]) {

    // do important things here

}
```

The problem is that this statement doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between NO, nil, and key doesn't exist. How can I make sure that this condition is met ONLY when isComplete is NO, and not when isComplete is nil or isComplete doesn't exist (no key)? How do I stop the false positives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something similar to this:

```
NSNumber* IsComplete;
IsComplete=[videoDictionary objectForKey:@"isComplete"];
if (IsComplete!=nil && ![IsComplete boolValue])
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is casting to a NSNumber important? Will it work the same without that step?

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually an issue. The dictionary *cannot contain* `BOOL`s directly, nor can it have `nil` as the value for a key. The value of the key `@"isComplete"` *must* be a valid object if it exists at all. If it's representing a boolean value, it's likely to be an `NSNumber`, and you should check the object's `boolValue`.

If the expression `[someDictionary objectForKey:@"aKey"]` evaluates as false, then it is only because there is no value for that key.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know dictionaries can't contain non-objects. My problem is that I don't want a value-less key to evaluate to false...I want it to evaluate to nil because otherwise it throws false positives when I only want to accept false, not an empty value.

Comment: `nil` is always false in a boolean context (like the condition of an `if` statement). To get "true" when the object exists, you use `obj != nil` or simply `!obj`.